# How do you originate an archetype contract from within a dapp?

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, archetype

I’m trying to figure out how to originate a new contract from within a dapp. I seem to have found what I am looking for here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/originate

Here is the example code I am looking at, for convenience:

```
// import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito';
// const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://jakartanet.ecadinfra.com');

// const genericMultisigJSONfile = require('./generic.json')
// generic.json is referring to Michelson source code in JSON representation

Tezos.contract
  .originate({
    code: genericMultisigJSONfile,
    storage: {
      stored_counter: 0,
      threshold: 1,
      keys: ['edpkuLxx9PQD8fZ45eUzrK3BhfDZJHhBuK4Zi49DcEGANwd2rpX82t'],
    },
  })
  .then((originationOp) => {
    println(`Waiting for confirmation of origination for ${originationOp.contractAddress}...`);
    return originationOp.contract();
  })
  .then((contract) => {
    println(`Origination completed.`);
  })
  .catch((error) => println(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));
```

However this appears to require the contract to be michelson source code in JSON representation. How can I convert my archetype smart contract into this format?

Or more broadly - am I taking the wrong approach here altogether? Is there an archetype specific tool or approach here?

For example, I am wondering if the storage parameter that plugs into contract.originate() will even to accept the custom archetype types from the "@completium/archetype-ts-types" library... ? (Because I haven't gotten past converting the smart contract into the right format I haven't been able to test this myself yet)

Any help is appreciated

--EDIT--

Just a note that I eventually found it easiest to use this command to generate the contract code as a json object already embedded in a javascript file: `completium-cli generate javascript test.arl --json >> testJSONmich.js`

In order to most easily update the storage, I used the instructions under 'option a' here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/originate/.

This allows an ordinary javascript object to be passed in with the storage variables and initialising parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a completium command to generate the Json Micheline:

```
completium-cli generate michelson mycontract.arl --json
```

This generates a Json structure, whose "code" field is what you pass to taquito for origination, and the "storage" field is the initial storage value.

For example, consider the following contract:

```
archetype simple

variable res : nat = 0

entry exec (n : nat) {
  res := n
}
```

The command above generates the following:

```
{
  "code":
    [  {  "prim": "storage",
          "args": [
            {  "prim": "nat"  }
          ]
       },
       {  "prim": "parameter",
          "args": [
            {  "prim": "nat",
               "annots": [
                 "%exec"
               ]
            }
          ]
       },
       {  "prim": "code",
          "args": [
            [  {  "prim": "UNPAIR"  },
            {  "prim": "DUP"  },
            {  "prim": "DIP",
               "args": [
                 {  "int": "1"  },
                 [  {  "prim": "SWAP"  },
                 {  "prim": "DROP",
                    "args": [
                      {  "int": "1"  }
                    ]
                 }  ]
               ]
            },
            {  "prim": "SWAP"  },
            {  "prim": "DROP",
               "args": [
                 {  "int": "1"  }
               ]
            },
            {  "prim": "NIL",
               "args": [
                 {  "prim": "operation"  }
               ]
            },
            {  "prim": "PAIR"  }  ]
          ]
       }  ]
  "storage":
    {  "int": "0"  };
}
```

If the contract has parameters, you then need to replace them somehow in the generated object.